# Customize vertex style when selecting features (point, line, polygon) in Openlayers 3?

Tags: styles, openlayers-3

I am trying to show the vertices on selected features in openlayers 3 by customizing their style. I have managed to do so for polygons, but need it dynamically on all feature types (point, line polygon)

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28092956/how-to-indicate-polygon-vertices-with-small-circles-using-openlayers) for polygons is using multiple styles, as shown below.

```
var styleFunction = function() {
        return [
          new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
              radius: 5,
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#00aaff'
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#00aaff', width: 2})
            }),
            geometry: function(feature) {
              var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
              return new ol.geom.MultiPoint(coordinates);
            }
          }),
          new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: "#00aaff",
              width: 3
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: "rgba(255,255,255,0.4)"
            })
          })
        ]
      }
```

This solution works for polygons, but when selecting lines the vertices don't show, and when selecting points my styleFunction breaks completely.

I get the following error on points:

```
TypeError: e is undefined SimpleGeometry.js:196
    setLayout SimpleGeometry.js:196
    setCoordinates MultiPoint.js:158
    e MultiPoint.js:25
    geometry (index):128
    Ua vector.js:128
    Ua vector.js:127
    renderFeature VectorLayer.js:404
    E VectorLayer.js:353
    <anonymous> (index):975
    prepareFrame VectorLayer.js:370
    renderFrame Map.js:159
    renderFrame_ PluggableMap.js:1232
    animationDelay_ PluggableMap.js:191
    <anonymous> (index):975
```

Can anyone help me modify the styleFunction in a way that it supports all feature types?

Thanks for any leads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle each type of geometry differently as `getCoordinates` returns different object of coordinates depending on the type of geometry passed. 
Check this

```
var styleFunction = function() {
        return [
          new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
              radius: 5,
              fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#00aaff'
              }),
              stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#00aaff', width: 2})
            }),
            geometry: function(feature) {
              var coordinates;
              if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == "LineString"){
                  coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
              } else if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == "Polygon"){
                  coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0];
              } else if (feature.getGeometry().getType() == "Pont"){
               //not 100% sure this would work!!!!
                  coordinates = [feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()];
               } else {
                  alert("maybe you need to handle also multi geometries");
               }
              return new ol.geom.MultiPoint(coordinates);
            }
          }),
          new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: "#00aaff",
              width: 3
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: "rgba(255,255,255,0.4)"
            })
          })
        ]
      }
```

Comment: First and last coordinates of a polygon ring are the same, there os no need to repeat them in the points `feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0].slice(0, -1)`